# Python: know function is called from a unittest?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unittest

Is there a way to know in Python if a function is called from the context of a unittest execution or a debugging run?

For the context, I am trying to unittest a code where I use functions that perform a database call. In order to avoid database calls during the test of that function (DB calls are tested separately), I am trying to make the DB IO functions aware of their environement and to mock when they are called within a unittest and log additional variables during a debug run.

My current aproach is to read/write environment variables, but it seems a little bit of an overkill and I think Python must have a better mechanism for that.

**Edit:**
Here is the example of a function I am trying to unittest:

```
from Database_IO import Database_read

def some_function(significance_level, time_range)
    data = Database_read(time_range)
    significant_data = data > significance_level
    return significant_data
```

Comment: Can't you inject the mock in your object? You're sort of trying to do it backward, which might be a sign your code isn't designed correctly.

Comment: You should mock the database call within your tests / testing framework. This keeps your application code clean.

Comment: But how can I do it if the call to the DB IO function is inside the function I willing to test?

Comment: You should inject your database object into the object you're testing. This is called dependency injection.

Comment: Mocking frameworks allow you to mock functions that are inside other functions. That's not an issue. Or, as mentioned, you can pass in the database object.

Comment: Can't really do a dependency injection because the function is imported from a different module and not is a method of a class nor a inner function of the function I am testing. As far as I understood from the `mock` library documentation, a mock injection is possible only in those two cases. Am I wrong?

Comment: It might be worth it to show a small example of what you're trying to test.

Comment: What's the problem?  mock `Database_read` object , or deeper inside it if you want to.  Absolutely *don't* put any test related conditionals into the application!

Comment: `mock.patch('mod.foo', ...)` mocks the function `foo` imported from `mod`, regardless of how deeply inside the test code it appears.

Comment: @chepner: thanks, didn't know it.

Comment: Ok, and how should I proceed if I need to mock a module before it is imported to avoid triggering the module-level set-up?

Comment: For instance to avoid module-level DB interface set-up. Or would doing something like this be a bad practice?

Comment: Instead of importing it with `import foo`, just mock the entire module: `foo = mock.Mock()`. You may need a significant amount of configuration of the resulting `Mock` instance in order for your test code to work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my opinion, if you write your function to behave in a different way when tested, you are not really testing it.

To test the function I'd `mock.patch()` the database object, and then check it has used correctly in your function.

The most difficult thing when you start using the mock library is to find [the correct object to replace](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch).

In your example, if in `your_module` you import the `Database_read` object from the `Database_IO` module, you can test it by using a code similar to the following

```
with mock.patch('your_module.Database_read') as dbread_mock:
    # prepare the dbread_mock
    dbread_mock.return_value = 10
    # execute a test call
    retval = some_function(3, 'some range')
    # check the result
    dbread_mock.assert_called_with('some range')
```